# Um programa que faz a soma de n números onde os ímpares serão desconsiderados, onde funciona como deveria

Tags: c, algoritmo, variáveis

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i, nmrs, n, soma = 0;

    printf("De quantos numeros quer fazer a soma? (impares serao desconsiderados)\n");
    scanf("%d", &nmrs);

    for (i = 1; i <= nmrs; i++)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            soma = soma + n;
        }
        printf("digite um numero:  ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

    }

    printf("A soma dos numeros pares que aqui apareceram: %d", soma);

}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Você está usando a variável `n` que foi declarada e não inicializada, então pode ter lixo na memória e esse valor lixo que já estava lá foi usado para soma. Não faz sentido usar o valor antes de pedir a primeira vez, mudando a ordem do código resolve isso. Aí aproveita e declara a variável só no uso, fica mais legível e óbvio (eu falo sempre que declarar antes é confuso, mas o pessoal sempre ensina desse jeito porque nos anos 70 era assim).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int nmrs, soma = 0;
    printf("De quantos numeros quer fazer a soma? (impares serao desconsiderados)\n");
    scanf("%d", &nmrs);
    for (int i = 1; i <= nmrs; i++) {
        int n;
        printf("digite um numero:  ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (n % 2 == 0) soma += n;
    }
    printf("A soma dos numeros pares que aqui apareceram: %d", soma);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WzZA7p). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/almbynac-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/SumEven.c).

Eu não mudei sua interpretação, mas pode ser que ela esteja errada. Pode ser que só deva contar os pares também e seu algoritmo conta os ímpares. Se não puder contar teria que colocar um `else` decrementando `i` para não contar o número que foi descartado.

Comment: obrigado man B)

Comment: @ArthurRibeiroDantas veja no [tour] que você pode aceitar a resposta se ela resolveu a questão para você. E pode votar na resposta também. Veja aí do lado esquerdo da resposta onde votar e aceitar.